# Python subprocess.call() in an .exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I just made a python program I wrote into an exe using py2exe.
Before, this code:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call("C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", shell=True)
```

opened command prompt. Now, when called in the exe, it gives "The System cannot find the path specified".

I'm at a loss as to why it would do this, since the path to command prompt is not changing.
Can anyone help me?

Edit: To put things into perspective, the project this is a part of can be found [here](https://github.com/olekgierczak/PCSpeechControl). The paths.txt is where the path that is being executed is. SpeechControl.py is the main file. What I want to emphasize is that when running the python script through the python command line or cmd, it DOES work completely fine, but when I make it an executable using py2exe, it does not. 
The idea of the program is that an executable can be run on voice command, and having cmd.exe was just an example. I didn't mention this, but I was also testing a path to spotify, which in my case is "C:/Users/Olek/AppData/Roaming/Spotify/spotify.exe". It gave the same "The System cannot find the path specified" message.

Comment: sometimes i just use **os.system('comman')** or if i need an object to hold results i use **obj = os.popen('command').read()**

Comment: 1. Use raw string literals: `r''` e.g., `r'C:\Users\...'` 2. Create a [*minimal* (e.g., a script that has only `subprocess.call` in it) but complete code example that demonstrates your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 3. `shell=True` *already* starts `cmd.exe` on Windows. What do you want to achieve with this code? 4. Don't put relevant info in the comments [edit] your question instead

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian In the program I'm using this call in, it calls a variable. How would I go about making the variable a raw string literal?

Comment: @OlekGierczak: if it is already in memory then you don't need to. `r'C:\User'`  and  `'C:\\User'` are the same -- string literals affect only how the objects are created when you type them in the Python source code. Have you tried to omit `shell=True` and run a hardcoded Windows program? Are you creating a Console application or GUI application (pass appropriate settings to py2exe)? Try the hello world script with [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) or [PyInstaller](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
 #this executes the statement in a cmd hence launches a cmd inside a cmd
 os.system("C:/Windows/system32/cmd.exe")
 #or this holds a reference to the opened process
 result = os.popen("C:/Windows/system32/cmd.exe").read()
 #or this
 subprocess.call("C:/Windows/system32/cmd.exe", shell=True)
```

Good luck